# How could one only allow one iOS device to pair to a BLE microcontroller?

Tags: ios, ios7, bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an iOS app that I have written and maintain, and was wondering what would be a good way to lock down the device to a BLE microcontroller.  I am currently using an iPod Touch which has BLE out of the box along with a BLuno microcontroller.  So far this combo has worked very well for me, however anyone who downloads the app I have been working on can pair to the BLuno microcontroller, which kind of defeats some of the security implementations put in by the app.  What would be a viable solution to locking down the microcontroller to a specific iOS device, that way other people couldn't hijack the microcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

You can "whitelist" your device by configuring the BLE chip using AT commands.

Since you're using this in an arduino environment then fire up the SoftwareSerial example sketch and select the correct rx and tx pins for your arduino and the correct baud rate of the BLE chip.

in the serial terminal send the following AT Commands

```
AT
AT+RADD?
```

this should reply with something like

```
OK
OK+RADD:7ED33C16D201
```

then set this mac to be whitelisted

```
AT+AD07ED33C16D201
AT+ALLO1
AT+RESET
```

To turn off whitelisting if something goes wrong do the following

```
AT+ALLO0
AT+RESET
```

I would suggest reading the HM Bluetooth Datasheet.  This will explain the AT codes and a lot more.

Comment: actually this is probably no good these days as devices tend to randomize their MAC's periodically